# What's the best way to protect drupal files folder from script execution on Windows Server?

Tags: php, security, drupal

**Drupal 7 comes with built-in .htaccess files to protect the files, tmp and private directories from script execution like malicious php, but doesn't provide a similar web.config file for Windows servers. I have looked around and couldn't find a proper solution yet.**

I did came across a solution for Wordpress which suggested to upload this simple web.config file to the wp-content/uploads folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The author stated:

> This tells IIS that handlers (such as PHP) may only read, and not
>   execute.

Could it work in the same way for Drupal? I did uploaded this file in my Drupals files folders and at least it didn't break anything. I was still able to upload files and the the styles were still properly applied.

Does anyone knows a beeter, more secure solution?

Update: I forgot to mention - if I try to access a php file from one of these directories I get a `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.` error, so it works at some level.

Comment: Did you put a PHP file into the files folder and try to download it?

Comment: Yes, I did. The server answers: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.